# tinymce textarea editor is ignoring &nbsp

Tags: knockout.js, tinymce-4

I have a record in database saved as "   aaaaaa a  "
for column Description.

Im retrieving this data in tinymce textarea like this:

```
ed.on('init',function(e) {
       tinyMCE.get(tinymce.editors.length-1).setContent(movie.Description());                       
});
```

movie.Description(): used to store the content in the editor and since it is saved as it should in database, i think this part is good, so only the part when i retreive it...

Is there anything that i can try to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not real familiar with tinymce but do you think maybe you need a custom binding for it to work with knockout?

http://jsfiddle.net/9euk9/312/

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.tinymce = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());  
            tinymce.init({selector: "textarea"  });
    tinymce.activeEditor.setContent('<pre>' + value + '</pre>');
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
         var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()); 
         tinymce.activeEditor.setContent('<pre>' + value + '</pre>');
    }
};
```